# Delete the [ORALCE] tag?

Tags: support, tags

There are no questions using this tag and it seems like just a "mis-spelled" Oracle tag that will never get used.

Comment: Very confused. Did you misspell the misspelling in your title?

Comment: I try to misspell something and I can't!! I meant [oralce] tag.

Comment: People misunderstand Oracle @Won't... they're actually fantastic (and cheap!) if you know what you're doing. I recognise that they appear completely evil at first inspection :-).

Comment: Why are you bothering to migrate stuff like this @Tim? Wouldn't it be better off deleted - it's a duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 11):

> There are no questions using this tag

This means that it will become auto-deleted. You don't have to take any action.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that and I didn't see or find where it says that in the FAQ.